# How do I detect if a web app was launched from home screen?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, web-applications

Recent versions of Chrome for Android allow the installation of a web page in the home screen, using the [web app manifest](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/).

But here's my question: how do I detect in Javascript whether the page was launched from the home screen?  I found a [page](https://web.dev/add-manifest/#display) advising the use of `window.matchMedia`, but this does not seem to work with Chrome 47 on Android.

Anyway, is there a solution at all for this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can check what is returned by `document.referrer` ?